# Can we write a closed subset of $\mathbb R^d$ as a union of connected sets?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $B$ be a closed subset$^1$ of $\mathbb R^d$.

Can we always write $B$ as the (finite / countable / uncountable) union of connected (or even path connected) subsets of $B$?

I guess the elements of such a union are what's being called the "[connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Connected_components)" of $B$, but I'm uncertain whether they always exist, if they are finite, countable or countable and which kind of connectedness notion they satisfy when the topological space in question is $\mathbb R^d$ (or maybe, more generally, a metric space).

---

$^1$ .I'm actually interested in the case where $B$ is the boundary of another closed subset of $\mathbb R^d$, but I guess this won't matter in the following. However, if I'm wrong, feel free to assume that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any subset of $\mathbb R^{d}$ is a union of singleton sets which are connected.

Comment: but aren't single points (singletons) in $\mathbb{R}^d$ separated, i.e. not connected ?

Comment: No, singelton sets are connected. You cannot write them as union of two non-empty sets so they don't have a  'separation'. @Physor

Comment: I think you are confusing 'separated from each other' for each of them being 'separated'.  @Physor

Comment: yes, thanks, I thought about a finite collection of single points as the set

Comment: Well, I thought this wouldn't be that trivial. Your argument does apply to any metric space (maybe even any Hausdorff space, or am I missing something?). What's the point of the "connected components" concept then?